# Problema haciendo preguntas: "El cuerpo de esta pregunta no cumple con nuestros estándares de calidad"

Tags: soporte, preguntas, filtros-de-calidad

Estoy intentado hacer preguntas en stackoverflow y por alguna extraña razón me pone lo siguiente:

> El cuerpo de esta pregunta no cumple con nuestros estándares de calidad. Asegúrate de que describe completamente tu problema, incluso lo que ya intentaste, y que se escribió con una gramática correcta.

Ahora mismo no me sale el error que escribí en el primer post pero mi pregunta era básicamente esta:

> [image: captura]

¿Qué debo hacer?

Comment: Para empezar, agregar a esta pregunta, la pregunta que querías publicar. :D

Comment: De todas formas me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje...no entiendo que tengo mal

Comment: me parece bien raro, agrega un pantallazo :D

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7YziO Ahora mismo no me sale el error que escribí en el primer post pero mi pregunta era básicamente esa y no se realmente que esta mal.

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta la puedes encontrar en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error):

> ### ¿Por qué veo un mensaje mencionando que mi pregunta no cumple con los estándares de calidad?
>
> En ocasiones los
>   usuarios se encuentran con el siguiente mensaje al publicar una
>   pregunta:
>
> > "Esta publicación no cumple con nuestros estándares
> >   de calidad."
>
> Si ves este mensaje significa que tu pregunta fue bloqueada
>   automáticamente por el servidor. Todas las preguntas nuevas son
>   sometidas a un filtro de "calidad mínima" que verifica algunos
>   indicadores básicos de una pregunta buena y completa. Asegúrate que tu
>   pregunta tiene lo siguiente:
>
> - Un título claro.
> - Una explicación razonable de cuál
>     es tu pregunta. Agrega todo el detalle que puedas.
> - Cualquier
>     investigación que hayas hecho pero que no fue suficiente para resolver
>     tu problema.
> - Cualquier investigación y búsqueda que hayas realizado pero que no haya sido suficiente para resolver el problema.
> - Un uso tan correcto como puedas
>     de la ortografía y gramática española.
>
> Las Preguntas
>   Frecuentes de la comunidad contienen más detalles.
>
> Para más información acerca de cómo hacer una buena pregunta,
>   revisa nuestra [Guía de cómo
>   preguntar](/help/how-to-ask).
>
> Si tu pregunta tiene todos estos elementos, aún sigue bloqueada y
>   consideras que es un error, [has clic aquí para
>   contactarnos](/contact).

Comment: ¿Traduciendo? El artículo está en español... bueno, parece que falta una frase